# Why does @Rollback annotation not work?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

That's my code:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {
  @Resource
  private UserDao userDao;

  @Test
  public void save1() {
    User user1 = new User("tom", "tom-pass");
    User user2 = new User("jerry  ", "jerry-pass");
    userDao.save(user1);
    userDao.save(user2);
  }

  @Test
  public void save2() {
    User user1 = new User("tom", "tom-pass");
    User user2 = new User("jerry  ", "jerry-pass");
    userDao.save(user1);
    userDao.save(user2);
    List<User> all = userDao.findAll();
    Assert.assertTrue(all.size() >= 2);
  }
}
```

After test,I found the 1st method can rollback automatically,but the 2nd method doesn't work,why?

Comment: You are testing your DAO, why not using @DataJpaTest instead? By default, data JPA tests are transactional and roll back at the end of each test.

Comment: @LuayAbdulraheem I changed my code to this, but the result still hasn't changed, and I've tried to add *@Rollback* and *@Transactional* annotations, but it's the same result.

Comment: Remove `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`, and use `@Autowired` instead of `@Resource`.

Comment: @LuayAbdulraheem Nothing changed.And if i remove **@AutoConfigureTestDatabase** ,I got an error **Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoConfigureTestDatabase.**

Comment: You need to test against an in-memory embedded database. Make sure in your pom.xml you have the following dependency:

`<dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>`